# Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'UIButton' in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift4

I'm trying to call a button function after loading it before viewDidLoad() like this:

```
@IBAction func tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(Date().dayNumberOfWeek() == 4) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tap(self)
```

This returns `Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'UIButton'`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people like to follow the convention of extracting the code for the IBAction out into a private function.

```
@IBAction func tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    presentAlertIfNecessary()
}
private func presentAlertIfNecessary() {
    if(Date().dayNumberOfWeek() == 4) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
         self.present(alert, animated: true)           
    }
}
```

This way you can call the function in viewDidAppear.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    presentAlertIfNecessary()
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer so far.

Answer (score 4):

The tap method is expecting a `UIButton`. But, in the `viewDidLoad` method, you are calling the tap method with `self` which is a `UIViewController`. They are two separate classes.

If you do not care about the class of the calling object, you can change the method declaration to

```
@IBAction func tap(_ sender: Any)
```

Comment: Before too many people up vote this, this is not a good solution. You should not specify `Any` for the sender. There are proper solutions that don't require using `Any` as a catch-all.

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty clear. You are passing a view controller to a method that is expecting a button.

Presumably your `tap` action is connected to some `UIButton` in your user interface which is why the `tap` method is expecting a `UIButton` argument.

Since it seems you wish to manually call this `tap` method from `viewDidLoad`, you should pass a reference to the button it is connected to.

Assuming you have an `IBOutlet` for the `UIButton`, then pass that outlet to the call to tap.

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton! // an example of your existing outlet
```

Change your line in `viewDidLoad` to:

```
tap(myButton)
```

Replace `myButton` with the actual name of your outlet.

Another option, since your `tap` method doesn't actually make use of the `sender` parameter, is to get rid of the parameter.

```
@IBAction func tap() {
    // your existing code
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` you simply do:

```
tap()
```

Comment: comment tap function and run , i think the problem caused by another part of your app

Comment: Do you actually have an outlet for your button? Don't simply add the example I showed in my answer since that will cause your crash. That was simply an example. It assumes you already had your own outlet and you need to pass your actual outlet to the `tap` method in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
@IBAction func tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if(Date().dayNumberOfWeek() == 4) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

         self.present(alert, animated: true)           
    }

}
```

Also , keep in mind that your code shows a UIAlertController in viewDidload which may not appear as view hierarchy is not yet loaded so better put the code in viewDidAppear like this

```
override  func viewDidAppear()
{
  tap(UIButton())
}
```

Also the condition **Date().dayNumberOfWeek() == 4** must be satisfied to see the alert

Comment: I’ll try your edited version, but the solution you posted just returns “terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException”

Comment: Do this @IBAction func tap(_ sender: UIViewController) and leave tap(self) as it is

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Do not change the signature of the `tap` method. Presumably it is tied to a button. Changing the signature will cause a crash when the button is tapped.

Comment: @rmaddy what do you mean?

Comment: @Sh_Khan This latest update, while it will work at the moment, isn't ideal. It's possible that the `tap` method might actually need to make use of the `sender` parameter in a future change to the code. Passing a dummy button from `viewDidAppear` could cause issues with that. Something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

The function is expecting a button type. If you have an IBOUtlet to the button you can pass that in instead.

```
class Controller: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(Date().dayNumberOfWeek() == 4) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tap(button)
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what my answer stated.